# display pdf without saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

So I am trying to adjust this function so instead of creating a new PDF file with the new fields value, then display new file to user then delete on exit.
to just create maybe a stream or byte array of this template with the new fields value and just display it for user.. is it possible?

```
private void fillPDFForm()
{
    string formFile = @"C:\fw4.pdf";
    string newFile = @"C:\New_fw4.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);

    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        // set form fields
        fields.SetField("name", "John Doe");
        fields.SetField("address", "xxxxx, yyyy");
        fields.SetField("postal_code", "12345");
        fields.SetField("email", "johndoe@xxx.com");

        // flatten form fields and close document
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Of-course it is possible by using `MemoryStream` instead of `FileStream` thus your code would look like:

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream, '\0', true))
    {
        AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

        // set form fields
        fields.SetField("name", "John Doe");
        fields.SetField("address", "xxxxx, yyyy");
        fields.SetField("postal_code", "12345");
        fields.SetField("email", "johndoe@xxx.com");

        // flatten form fields and close document
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
    }
    return memStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Great quick answer! Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the content type for the response to application/pdf ?

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))
```

to

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), "application/pdf"))
```

---

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)))

    private void fillPDFForm()
    {
        string formFile = @"C:\fw4.pdf";
        string newFile = @"C:\New_fw4.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);

        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), "application/pdf"))
        {
            AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

            // set form fields
            fields.SetField("name", "John Doe");
            fields.SetField("address", "xxxxx, yyyy");
            fields.SetField("postal_code", "12345");
            fields.SetField("email", "johndoe@xxx.com");

            // flatten form fields and close document
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Close();
        }
    }
```